# If a kotlin script in KMM uses Java classes, will it work for multiple platforms?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I am new to KMM but know that expressly declared java classes will not be compiled into a multiplatform form in multiplatform mobile.  However,  if a kotlin class uses java classes (java.net.URL in this case) with that class work across multiple platforms? If not what is a workaround that will?

Comment: No you can't use any java code in shared module, you need to create expect class URL in shared code and implement it on each platform. Actual implementation can also be done with typealias(`actual typealias URL = java.net.URL`) so each platform will see it as it's own url type. in this case if some functional has different function name on different platforms, you can create shared API with except extension functions.

Comment: Generally, you look for some library which is already KMM in the first place - e.g. Ktor should have it's own url class, and if only need to use the class from shared code, you can use it. But if you need to create API to be used from platform side, you have to build it by yourself.